# Not getting candy for Pokemon transfer

Tags: pokemon-go

I was transferring 3 different common Pokemons (my first transfers) and did not get any candy for it.

I picked one to Transfer, pressed Transfer button then Yes.
Nothing happened, just the Yes/No dialog closed, I still saw the same Pokemon with Transfer ability in front of me.

Exiting Pokemon details view, particular Pokemon disappeared for good, I thought that it is supposed to work like that, but I got eventually no candy for that...

When and how are candies assigned to my account?

P.S.
This happened 3 times as I tried.

Comment: Can you verify that even though the dialogue box doesn't appear to tell you that you got 1 candy, that your count did increase for that family?

Comment: I checked very carefully before/after transfer for my 2nd and 3rd transfer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is another issue that many continually experience. There have been multiple occasions where I transfer a Pokemon, but I do not receive the candy as I should. Typically when this happens, it occurs during a server connection blip and something goes terrible wrong.

I have noticed that transfers appears to be more affective while connected to a WI-FI network rather than 3G/4G Mobile Data, so it may be in your best interest to wait until you have a reliable connection before transfering.

Unfortunately, as with every other issue, the only thing we can do is wait for Niantic to finally get around to fixing all these bugs.

Comment: I was on Wifi, probably averagely strong.. must have been a server/app issue it self.

Comment: @Aziris Unfortunately, as much as we don't want it to be, server issues have to be the answer here. They've been notoriously awful in the past week or so, and our best bet is to bite the pokeball and keep trucking through.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting the Candy ? It just happened to me and I thought back to this question. The Pokemon was gone and the Candy wasn't given out, it also said there has been an error. I swiped the app closed, and re started it. The pokemon was still gone, but I got the candy this time...

Comment: @ИвоНедев I am positive. I restarted the app and the candy count did not increase. Technology has never liked me, so I guess it's just wanting me to suffer

Comment: **Good news 1 day later** : Pokemons that dissapeared for no candy are back!  Most probably they where temporarily not displayed in your "zoo" anymore and required status re-read from server where no action was actually taken.  Try closing screens up to main screen and check again.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes even if the yes/no dialog closes when you press yes, the pokemon is not transfered. and when you close the pokemon details window, a pop up show saying there was an error. it shouldt disappear. are you sure the num of candies do not increase?

wait to do this process until the connection is perfect to be sure is being done alright

Comment: I was not sure for first transfer, but for 2nd and 3rd I explicitly checked candy count before/after. No error screen as well. Will restart app for better results.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this too after transferring a lot of Pokemon and was worried I missed out on the candy. The Pokemon disappeared but the candy number did not increase. I restarted my phone and relaunched the app and all of the Pokemon I just transferred came back into my inventory.

Hopefully this works for you and you can get the candy the next time when the severs are working better

Answer (score 0):

The game is buggy and does that sometimes. It seems like when it's working they all work and the opposite. I always start with a Pidgy transfer to make sure the system is functioning properly then transfer important pocket monsters :)